# Do we need the [rpg-pop-culture] tag when we have [history-of-gaming]?

Tags: discussion, tags, synonymization

The tag description for [rpg-pop-culture](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rpg-pop-culture) says:

> For questions related to the pop culture surrounding RPGs. The pop culture may be famous events, real-life legends, well-known lore, or other pop culture items.

The tag description for [history-of-gaming](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/history-of-gaming) says:

> This tag covers questions about the entire history of role-playing games: the history of game companies, trends within the hobby, developments of new kinds of mechanics, and gaming's place in culture.

These seem to be *very* similar, both in description and in content covered, and it begs the question: when does a pop culture phenomenon become a facet of gaming history?

Should we synonym [rpg-pop-culture](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rpg-pop-culture) to [history-of-gaming](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/history-of-gaming), should we improve the tag descriptions so they are more notably distinct, should we leave them as is, or something else?

Answer (score 13):

### There's a distinction to make between game development and game play/discussion.

Many questions in [history-of-gaming](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/history-of-gaming) are about the early development of various games and play practices. I can see a desire to distinguish these from common elements in the conversation of gaming which were nonetheless never codified outside of discussion forums, and [rpg-pop-culture](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rpg-pop-culture) seems as good a bin for that as any.

There is some overlap, of course; successive editions of, say, D&D, or even the development of D&D out of Chainmail, relied to some extent on the experiences people had during actual play of the relevant game. [history-of-gaming](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/history-of-gaming) should probably cover those play experiences that shaped later game development as well.

#### Proposal

In light of this, the [history-of-gaming](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/history-of-gaming) tag wiki should be amended to

> This tag covers questions about the historical development of role-playing games: the history of game companies, trends within the hobby, developments of new kinds of mechanics, and how gaming's place in culture affected these developments.
>
> For questions about popular elements of gameplay or game discussion, consider [rpg-pop-culture](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rpg-pop-culture). For identifying gaming products from history, also consider [product-identification](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/product-identification). For definitions of gaming terms and jargon, also consider [terminology](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/terminology).

The [rpg-pop-culture](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rpg-pop-culture) tag wiki should be amended to:

> This tag covers questions about the pop culture surrounding RPGs: famous events, real-life legends, well-known lore, or other items. If it's more famous as an element of gameplay or game discussion than it is for any appearance in a published rulebook, it's RPG pop culture.
>
> For questions about the process of game development, including gameplay or game discussion that would go on to inform game development, consider [history-of-gaming](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/history-of-gaming). For definitions of gaming terms and jargon, also consider [terminology](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/terminology).  For identifying gaming products from history, also consider [product-identification](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/product-identification).

Comment: Is there an action item here, or “leave everything as is”?

Comment: @ThomasMarkov Ah, good point. I've amended a proposal.